# Need to convert the following data to JSON

Tags: json

I have a code which is writing the output to a file in the following format.

```
Application-Id : application_xxxx_xxxx
Application-Name : hive-job
Application-Type : MAPREDUCE
User : mapr
Queue : xdev
Start-Time : 1234567
Finish-Time : 1234567
Progress : 0%
State : FAILED
Final-State : FAILED
Tracking-URL : N/A
RPC Port : -1
AM Host : N/A
Aggregate Resource Allocation : 0 MB-seconds, 0 vcore-seconds
Diagnostics : Application rejected by queue placement policy
```

---

I need the above data to be converted to json format.

Comment: You need to add more informatio. Like what language you are using, what is the object you are pushing to the file. You cant take a random sentence and just make it a json string it doesnt work like that sorry

Comment: Can i convert the data using python or using sed ?

Comment: Well tbh it looks like the headers of your API call, and not the data, so you might need to actually get the data out of your body response, and then that should be in json, or easily converted.

Comment: I have converted some of what you have got to show you what it should look like: { 
"Application-Id" : "application_xxxx_xxxx", 
"Application-Nam" : "hive-job",
"Application-Type" : "MAPREDUCE"
}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) solution, which assumes you want to create a JSON object:

```
jq -Rn '[inputs | capture("(?<key>[^ ]*) : (?<value>.*)") ] | from_entries' input.txt
```

Of course you might want to tweak this, e.g. to deal with trailing blanks and the like.

One small advantage of jq is that if it produces any output, the output will be guaranteed to be valid JSON.

### Output

With the given input, the output would be:

```
{
  "Application-Id": "application_xxxx_xxxx",
  "Application-Name": "hive-job",
  "Application-Type": "MAPREDUCE",
  "User": "mapr",
  "Queue": "xdev",
  "Start-Time": "1234567",
  "Finish-Time": "1234567",
  "Progress": "0%",
  "State": "FAILED",
  "Final-State": "FAILED",
  "Tracking-URL": "N/A",
  "Port": "-1",
  "Host": "N/A",
  "Allocation": "0 MB-seconds, 0 vcore-seconds",
  "Diagnostics": "Application rejected by queue placement policy"
}
```